# Hide a div when clicked outside of it

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, hide

This question has been asked multiple times, however none of the answers seem to work for me.

The css of the div is as follows:

```
#info{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
  height: 50%;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: rgba(187, 187, 187, .8);
}
```

I tried to use the following code:

```
$("#info").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(){
  $("#info").hide();
});
```

as well as this code:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var container = $("#info");

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Yet whenever i click on the div it also disappears, no clue why but it does.
Any thing else that might work?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As your target has `id=info`, so you can try:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {

  // check that your clicked
  // element has no id=info

  if( e.target.id != 'info') {
    $("#info").hide();
  }
});
```

You can also try:

```
$(document).click(function() {

  if( this.id != 'info') {
    $("#info").hide();
  }

});
```

#### According to comment

```
$(document).click(function(e) {

    // check that your clicked
    // element has no id=info
    // and is not child of info
    if (e.target.id != 'info' && !$('#info').find(e.target).length) {
        $("#info").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: One question tough (it works perfectly so far) however when you click on a <h1> tag or just text it also disappears (logic). Is there a fix for this too?

Comment: @Gooey i.e `h1` tag or `text` within `info` div?

Comment: Yes, if i click now on text (either plain text or text between the <h1> tags) the div also hides. Is there a way to let the "children" of this div also be part of the "dont hide" function?

Comment: Thanks, the updated code works fine with child elements.

Answer (score 5):

To ensure you have a solution that works on iPads too, then you need to use the following function trigger instead:

```
$(document).on("mousedown touchstart",function(e){
  var $info = $('#info');
  if (!$info.is(e.target) && $info.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $info.hide();
  }
});
```

Similarly, if you are looking to cover off mouseup, add 'touchend':

```
$(document).on("mouseup touchend",function(e){
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Attach an `onclick` event handler to the `document` object:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {   
    if(e.target.id != 'info') {
        $("#info").hide();   
    } 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aUjRG/

Here is a solution in pure JavaScript to help you better understand what it happening:

```
function hideInfo(){
    if(window.event.srcElement.id != 'info'){
        document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'none';
    }
}

document.onclick = hideInfo;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mmzc8/

Both solutions will check if the location that the user clicked was on the element with an ID of `info`.  Assuming that the user did not click on the `info` element, then hide the `info` element.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, this is the best for me.

```
jQuery('.button_show_container').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('.container').slideToggle('fast'); 
    e.stopPropagation();
});

jQuery(document).click(function() {
        jQuery('.container').slideUp('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class only for check on mouse click that specific div or any within that div element clicked or not.

```
$(document).click(function(e){            
    if ( !$(e.target).hasClass("[class name for check]") &&
         $("[element class or id]").css("display")=="block" ) {
            //...code if clicked out side div
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with plain JavaScript, without need of JQuery:

```
const hide = (elem) => {
    elem.style.display = 'none';
};

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const menuContainer = document.getElementById('menuContainer');
  if (!menu.contains((event.target))) {
    hide(menuContainer)
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below solution. It's even working recursive:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7385673/3910232

Comment: This is a pure copy without any references. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7385673/4103909