# jQuery Click Handler on Outer Container Gets Fired When Inner Container is Clicked Too

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a custom class called `masked` on the `body` tag. In the middle of the page, I have a `DIV` with about 50% width and height of the page.

I am trying to attach a click handler only to the `body.masked` selector, but the problem is that whenever the inner `DIV` is clicked, the click handler on that `body.masked` selector is also fired.

As if the `DIV` in the middle is "transparent". How do I avoid that?

Here's some code:

```
$('body.masked').click(function(){
  alert();
})
```

And HTML:

```
<body class="masked">
  <div style="width:50%;height:50%;text-align:center;>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of [event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing).

It makes an event happened in a child element to bubble to the top of the event tree. That is why it is happening.

In the event handler you can check the `e.target` value to check where there event had occured.

ex:

```
$('.top').on('click', function(e){
    console.log(e, e.currentTarget, e.target, this);
    if($(e.target).is(this)){
        console.log('proceed')
    }
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jnt2p/)

Comment: Also, for future readers, this answer might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545518/hide-a-div-when-clicked-outside-of-it?rq=1